# How to use jquery query string object plugin - set, empty, remove methods not working

Tags: jquery, query-string

I am using this plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

The 'get' and 'toString' methods work fine, but the 'set', 'empty', and 'remove' methods do not work. In the author's demonstration, he only uses 'get' and 'toString', but in his example on the top of the page, he uses the rest of the "nice-to-have" methods.

Anyone run into this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the `set` method, and it works just fine:

```
alert($.query.set("section", 5).set("action", "do").toString());
```

Output:

```
?section=5&action=do
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I now understand that the functions just return the querystring. Is there a way to dynamically manipulate the querystring after the page has loaded?

Comment: @Andee: No, you can't change the query string of the current document, just as you can't change the URL. You can assign a new query string to the window.Location object, but that means that the page reloads.

Answer (score 3):

Functions like `.set` return modified copy of original query-object. If you wish to modify existing object (*for example one created using `.load(string)` method*), use `.SET` method.
Modifying of query string is possible now using HTML5: search for `window.history.pushState()`. Setting `window.location.href` variable will result in reloading page.