# How to store program state in URL query string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I read, *and write*, to the query string?

```
var pageNumber = QueryString['pageNumber'];
var pageSize   = QueryString['pageSize'];

$('#next').click(function() { 
    QueryString['pageNumber'] = ++pageNumber;
    refresh(); 
});

function refresh() { /** get data and update page here **/ }
```

This, of course, will allow users to copy and paste URLs that contain partial program state.

Is there an API similar to `QueryString` (used above)?

Comment: Never seen that `QueryString` object before, where are you getting it from?

Comment: @Barmar - "Is there an API similar to QueryString (used above)?"; I think the point is the OP hasn't seen that object either and wants one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jquery query string object plugin - set, empty, remove methods not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906141/how-to-use-jquery-query-string-object-plugin-set-empty-remove-methods-not-wo)

Answer (score 2):

As Richard mentioned, changing the query string by assigning to window.location.search will trigger a page reload.

For this reason, it is common practice to instead encode client-side state in the fragment identifier ("hash routing", which is compatible with older browsers) or to manipulate the path using [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (part of HTML5). pushState requires serverside support, which usually takes the form of a wildcard route.

Libraries such as [Director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) or [Backbone Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) provide abstractions that will work with either technique.

**Update**
I didn't know this until doing research for this answer, but it is possible to manipulate the query string via pushState (which makes sense given that it's part of the URL). As the author of [this demo](http://bit.ly/aC4Jsk) points out, this allows using pushState without any special serverside support.

Answer (score 0):

In-browser JavaScript can access the query string using the Browse Object Model's `window.location.search` property. There isn't a lot of native support for parsing that query string though. (see also [How can I get a specific parameter from location.search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523266/how-can-i-get-a-specific-parameter-from-location-search))

Perhaps something like this will do?

```
var GET = {}; // I've taken the liberty of re-naming your `QueryString` object
              // to just `GET`, kind of in the style of PHP.
              // Mostly because I find it confusing to refer to something which
              // is not a string (it is an object/map) as a string.
var queryString = window.location.search.replace(/^\?/, ''); // but this: *this* is a string!
queryString.split(/\&/).forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
    var paramName = keyValuePair.replace(/=.*$/, ""); // some decoding is probably necessary
    var paramValue = keyValuePair.replace(/^[^=]*\=/, ""); // some decoding is probably necessary
    GET[paramName] = paramValue;
});

var pageNumber = GET['pageNumber']?Number(GET['pageNumber']):0;

$('#next').click(function() { 
    GET['pageNumber'] = ++pageNumber;
    refresh(); 
});

function refresh() {
    var newQueryString = Object.keys(GET).reduce(function(keyValuePairs, paramName) {
        keyValuePairs.push(escape(paramName)+"="+escape(GET[paramName]));
        return keyValuePairs;
    }, []).join('&');

    window.location.search = "?"+newQueryString;
}
```

Comment: Does calling window.location.search not trigger a page load?

Comment: @landon9720 - That depends on what you mean by "calling". Reading the value will not trigger a page load; writing to it will. If you don't want that the `window.location.hash` value (which corresponds to the [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) can be changed without triggering a page load.